# Let A be an n × m matrix with rank(A) < m and m ≤ n... How do I prove this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that it is always possible to write A = QR, where Q is an n × m matrix with orthonormal columns and R is upper-triangular?

Comment: I'm not sure why the rank hypotheses are there; QR factorization works regardless of the rank and shape of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?  You can form $Q$ by Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization (on the columns) and then show that R will be upper-triangular.